# Contradiction of uniqueness

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm endeavouring to prove that $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}:m\ne 0 \wedge n\ne 0\implies m\cdot n\ne 0$.

**Preliminary definitions** If $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers.

1. $x<y\iff \exists c\in \mathbb{N};\ c\ne 0: x+c=y$

**Remark** It's provable that such a number $c$ in definition $1$ is unique.

*Proof*. We'll prove its contrapositive, \begin{align*}m\cdot n=0\implies m=0\vee n=0\tag{$a$}\end{align*}Let $p,q,r$ be propositions. From the tauotlogies $p\vee q\equiv \sim p\implies q$ and $ p\implies (q\implies r)\equiv (p\wedge q)\implies r$ we may notice that $(a)$ is logically equivalent to show \begin{align*}m\cdot n=0\wedge m\ne 0\implies n=0\end{align*} which is what we'll show instead of $(a)$. To do so, let $m$ and $n$ be arbitrarily chosen natural numbers. If $m\ne 0$, then $m>0$ because $m\in \mathbb{N}$ ($\forall x\in \mathbb{N}:x\ge 0$). So by hypothesis, we know $m>m\cdot n$. Meaning there is a unique natural number, say $p$, different from $0$ such that $m\cdot n+p=m$ or simply there is a unique \begin{align*}p\in \mathbb{N};\ p\ne 0: p=m\tag{$b$}\end{align*} because $m\cdot n=0$. But given that $p$ is unique and $m$ is any natural number $p=m$ is an absurd. Hence, $(a)$ is true because its logical equivalent is vacuously true.

**My question.** In this context, is $p=m$ a contradiction because of the uniquess of $p$?
**Remark** Assume $0\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: You're right. I'll edit right away.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right I'll edit immediately.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Just edited it!

Comment: But your $p$ depends on the $m$ you arbitrarily chose before. So you don't get a contradiction since the unique $p$ might just be equal to that $m$ you previously chose.

Comment: @coffeemath I understand. Thank you.

Comment: $p$ is not what we might call "absolutely and condition-lessly unique". Instead, the uniqueness of $p$ is "unique relative to what $m$ is", since its existence and uniqueness depends on a particular $m$. In general, you cannot go from "for every $m$ there exists a unique $p$..." to "there exists a unique $p$ such that for every $m$..." You prove the former, but claim for your "contradiction" that you established the latter. You did not.